# Using alertify with ajax delete

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, alertify

I was using the default confirm box to delete a record with ajax and it worked proberly.
here is the working code
http://pastebin.com/HZxDVAgU
But when I userd alertify it deletes the record but without hiding it.
here is the non-working code
http://pastebin.com/7q1sH5gM

that is the code which hides the record

```
  $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
```

Comment: `opacity` only accepts a numeric value. Is that supposed to be `opacity : 0`?

Comment: No, the same code worked with the default confirm box. thank you

Comment: @BlackSheep it accepts strings too, "In addition to numeric values, each property can take the strings 'show', 'hide', and 'toggle'. These shortcuts allow for custom hiding and showing animations that take into account the display type of the element." ref: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward That's true, I knew `height` and `width` properties accept `toggle` for example, but I didn't know `animate` accepts such values for `opacity`, thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the alertify callbacks `this` refer to window, to refers to the callee object you can use your `element` variable that stores the original element reference.

Code:

```
        element.parents(".record").animate({
            backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7"
        }, "fast")
            .animate({
            opacity: "hide"
        }, "slow");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/PUh6f/